# Distribution function and $L^p$ spaces.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I saw the result below without a proof and I would like to see it.

> **Result:**
>   Let $g$ a nonnegative and measurable function in $\Omega$ and $\mu_{g} $ its distribuction function, i.e.,
>   \begin{equation}
> \mu_{g}(t)= |\{x\in \Omega : g(x)>t\}|, t>0.
> \end{equation}
>   Let $\eta>0$ and $M>1$ be constants. Then, for $0<p<\infty,$
>   \begin{equation}
> g \in L^{p}(\Omega) \Leftrightarrow \sum_{k\ge 1} M^{pk} \mu_{g}(\eta M^k) = S < \infty.  
> \end{equation}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A consequence of Fubini's theorem for non-negative functions is that for any $p>0$,
$$\int_{\Omega}g(x)^pdx=\int_0^{+\infty}p\mu_g(t)t^{p-1}dt=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\int_{\eta M^k}^{\eta M^{k+1}}p\mu_g(t)t^{p-1}dt.$$
Let $a_k:=\int_{\eta M^k}^{\eta M^{k+1}}p\mu_g(t)t^{p-1}dt$. Consider the case $p\geq 1$. Since $\mu_g$ is decreasing and $t\mapsto t^{p-1}$ is increasing, we have 
$$\mu_g(\eta M^{k+1})\eta M^k(M-1)\eta^p (M^k)^{p-1}\leq a_k\leq \mu_g(\eta M^k)(M-1)M^k\eta^{p-1}(M^{k+1})^{p-1},$$
hence 
$$C_1\mu_g(\eta M^{k+1})M^{(k+1)p}\leq a_k\leq C_2\mu_g(\eta M^k)M^{kp}.$$
This gives the wanted equivalence.

When $p<1$, a similar argument applies.